# Merge two matplotlib figure.Figure or axes.Axes objects into a new one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an external function which returns a Figure object, and in this situation, each Figure object is composed of exactly one Axes object.
I want to compose a new figure consisting of these two figures (let's say horizontal joining).
So ideally, I would like to say:

```
fig1, fig2, joined = CreateFig( data1 ), CreateFig( data2 ), Figure()
subp1, subp2 = joined.add_subplot( 121 ), joined.add_subplot( 122 )
subp1, subp2 = fig1.get_axes()[0], fig2.get_axes()[0]
joinedFig.savefig( 'joined.eps' )
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, as the axes retrieved belong to `fig1` and `fig2`, not `joinedFig`.
The axes also cannot be merely duplicated by `copy.deepcopy()`.

In my example, I am referring to `figure.Figure()` instantiation.  While a search did lead me to see that `pyplot.figure()` is the development team's recommended instantiation technique, it doesn't change the question: is there any way to do `Axes`/`Figure` copy construction and `Figure` construction via composition of copied `Axes`?

Answer (score 3):

Can you modify `CreateFig`? If so, there is an easy solution: create the desired figure and axes first, then pass the axes to `CreateFig`, and let `CreateFig` manipulate the `axes` object:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def CreateFig(data, ax):
    ax.plot(data)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
data = np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))
CreateFig(data, axs[0])
data = np.linspace(-2,2,100)**2
CreateFig(data, axs[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No need to create a function really, this works:`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2); ax1.plot(data1); ax2.plot(data2)`